# Please [slot] a better title here

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are [713 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot+or+slots) tagged with either [slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot) or [slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slots). While [slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot) apparently is *"a method callback in some gui frameworks like QT"* and [slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slots) a *"python language feature to reduce size of object instances"* ([docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots)), both get frequently misused to describe the [HTML Slot API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) and its "copy cat" implementations like [Vue.js Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) (which have three competing tags by themselves). This has gotten to the point where the majority of newer questions of both tags are about HTML slots instead of the original tag meanings, rendering the tags useless.

Something needs to be done. One possible solution would be:

- retag qt-related questions to a new [signals-and-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals-and-slots)  tag (thanks cody-gray!)
- retag python-related questions to a new [python-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-slots) tag
- retag web-component-related questions to a new [html-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-slots) tag
- retag vue-related questions to [vuejs-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs-slots)
- delete and blacklist [slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot) and [slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slots)

What do you think?

Comment: If it's not too much bother please edit the question with a link to the relevant Python documentation and an approximate breakdown of how many posts there are per language tag/subject in the `slot` tag.

Comment: The Qt concept should really be tagged [signals-and-slots]; there don't need to be separate tags for [qt-signals] and [qt-slots].

Comment: This lead me to discover that there are, in fact, _three_ competing tags for Vue's slot feature: [[tag:v-slot]], [[tag:vue-slot]], and [[tag:vuejs-slots]]. Could we synonymize & merge those to a one as well? Not sure which should be the main, but there definitely shouldn't be 3 lol

Comment: @zcoop98 the synomization should be a separate request, it's something we can do as soon as we decide which tag to use.  In contrast, It'll be a long time until this burn happens.

Comment: It also attracts [spam for slot machines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74124475/5211833)

Comment: @zcoop98 [done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423160/synonymize-v-slot-and-vue-slot-into-vuejs-slots)

Comment: Idea for a punny title: We should remove this tag’s [slot]