# Synonymize v-slot and vue-slot into vuejs-slots

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Please synonymize [v-slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v-slot) and [vue-slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-slot) into [vuejs-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs-slots). They are the same thing.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420903/7910454